# Rename excel worksheet VB.net with Interop

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have the below interop code where I use "excel.Worksheets.Add()" to create my sheet in already available excel book (this becomes my active sheet automatically). During this excel assigns a default name automatically. Please let me know every time I add a sheet using "excel.Worksheets.add() I should rename it to a meaningful name.

```
        Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        Try
        excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
        excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Satish\TestExcel\vbexcel.xlsx")
        Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
        Dim diff As Integer = 1
        ' if you want column header from dgv elese omit the block 
        '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
        excel.Worksheets.Add()


        For j = 0 To DataGridView4.ColumnCount - 1


            excel.ActiveSheet.cells(1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).Name

        Next
        diff += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you set the result of `excel.Worksheets.Add()` to a variable (ie. `Dim WS as Worksheet = excel.Worksheets.Add()`), you should then be able to directly assign a new value to that variable's `name` property.

Taking the given code as a framework...

```
    Dim excel As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Try
    excel = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Satish\TestExcel\vbexcel.xlsx")
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim diff As Integer = 1
    ' if you want column header from dgv elese omit the block 
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' 
    Dim WS as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet = excel.Worksheets.Add()
    WS.Name = "Enter the name here"
    For j = 0 To DataGridView4.ColumnCount - 1


        excel.ActiveSheet.cells(1, j + 1) = DataGridView1.Columns(j).Name

    Next
    diff += 1
```

Comment: Im a need based coder. If you don't mind can you show me what you explained in a code.

Comment: And done. As an aside, have you considered using an ```Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel``` statement at the top of your code file so you don't need to put that on a bunch of other declarations?

Comment: Meh, sometimes people learn better from examples - and this wasn't exactly a tough slot-in. I would certainly hope someone working on a system in a given language was familiar enough with it to slot in two lines of code, at least...

Comment: My goal is not to take a piece of code and directly put in my work. What I meant was I'm not a software guy but a natural disaster analyst. So I was trying to learn and do something side by side. I was able to get myself upto a point where I was able to achieve something and after considerable time I asked for help. When in doubt is it wrong to ask someone to clarify??

Comment: @ Psychemaster - Your help is greatly appreciated. I was able to learn something today. Yeah I know it will be simple and look nasty for others..but for people like me we need encouragemet from experts like you to learn things.